# Running SonarQube on TeamCity

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, typescript2.0, sonarqube-scan, software-quality

I am running sonarqube on teamcity, I have installed the plugin and I can see the installed service, but when I add it to the build step, I get an error.

I checked on the machine and the sonarqube service isn't running. Nothing say that I need to install the sonarscanner on the server.

Can you please advise.

> ERROR: SonarQube server [dev-ci-01:9000] can not be reached
>   [10:52:12]ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   [10:52:12]org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
>   [10:52:12]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
>   [10:52:12]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getBootstrapIndex(Jars.java:100)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getScannerEngineFiles(Jars.java:76)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
>   [10:52:12]  ... 8 more
>   [10:52:12]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url: dev-ci-01:9000/batch/index
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:142)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:109)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:98)
>   [10:52:12]  at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getBootstrapIndex(Jars.java:96)
>   [10:52:12]  ... 12 more
>   [10:52:12]ERROR: 
>   [10:52:12]ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [10:52:12]Process exited with code 1

Comment: What is the problem after starting SonarQube?

Comment: Sonarqube service did not start on the server as it was installed via plugin. Should I install it?

Comment: Looking [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/SonarQube+Integration)  i think that the SonarQube server is not installed for you. See [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server) for the instructions you have to follow.

Comment: Thanks all, I changed the sonarqube server to be localhost:9000 and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I changed the sonarqube server to be localhost:9000 and it is working now